# How to do inner join in SQLite with multiple database helpers classes in android

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, inner-join

I have 2 database tables in my java android app.

I have 2 helpers, one for each table.

```java
public class SyncStudentsHelperextends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "SyncStudentsHelper";

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "students";
    private static final String COL1 = "field";
    private static final String COL2 = "field";
    private static final String COL3 = "field";
    private static final String COL4 = "field";
    private static final String COL5 = "field";

    public SyncStudentsHelper (Context context) {
        super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 2);
    }
}
```

I have a similar table for teachers.

My question is how to do inner join query between 2 tables.

Here is my attempt.

```java
public Cursor getinfo() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM students Inner Join teachers ON student.matchingfield = teachers.matchingfield" ;
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;
}
```

I get this error:

```
no such table: teachers(code 1): , while compiling:
```

My question is, because I have 2 different database helper files, how to do inner SQLite inner join from 2 tables.

**EDIT**

My query is on the student's helper class as below.

```
public class SyncStudentsHelperextends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "SyncStudentsHelper";

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "students";
    private static final String COL1 = "field";
    private static final String COL2 = "field";
    private static final String COL3 = "field";
    private static final String COL4 = "field";
    private static final String COL5 = "field";

    public SyncStudentsHelper (Context context) {
        super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 2);
    }
}  

//Return Cursor type
public Cursor getinfo() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String  attached = "attached_teacher";
    db.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE  SyncTeachers.teachers AS teachersdatabase ");
     String query = "SELECT * FROM students Inner Join teachersdatabase.teachers ON students.matchingfield = teachersdatabase.teachers.matchingfield " ;
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: *I have 2 different database helper files*, Why? Use only 1 SQLiteOpenHelper class for as many tables as you need then uninstall the app from the device and rerun to recreate the database and rerun.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [attach](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) one of the databases to the other without opening the attached database or have a single database that contains both tables.

Noting that you refer to the attached database via the given schema e.g. if using `ATTACH path_to_2nd_db AS seconddb` Then you would refer to the table in the attached database as `seconddb.the_table_name`

However, it appears that the reason why you have two databases is that in the seperate helpers you use the table name as the database name (based upon your SyncStudentsHelper class (which is missing the space between the class name and the extends keyword)).

I would suggest that you have a single DatabaseHelper that has both tables in the same database.

## Single Database Example

The database helper :-

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "Students_and_Teachers";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TEACHERS_TABLE_NAME = "teachers";
    public static final String STUDENTS_TABLE_NAME = "students";
    public static final String COL1 = "matchingfield";
    public static final String COL2 = "field1";
    public static final String COL3 = "field2";
    public static final String COL4 = "field3";
    public static final String COL5 = "field4";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String create_teachers_table_sql =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TEACHERS_TABLE_NAME +
                        "(" +
                        COL1 + " INTEGER," +
                        COL2 + " TEXT," +
                        COL3 + " TEXT," +
                        COL4 + " TEXT," +
                        COL5 + " TEXT" +
                        ")"
                ;
        String create_students_table_sql =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + STUDENTS_TABLE_NAME +
                        "(" +
                        COL1 + " INTEGER," +
                        COL2 + " TEXT," +
                        COL3 + " TEXT," +
                        COL4 + " TEXT," +
                        COL5 + " TEXT" +
                        ")"
                ;
        db.execSQL(create_teachers_table_sql);
        db.execSQL(create_students_table_sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public long insertStudent(long teacherToMatch, String studentName) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL1,teacherToMatch);
        cv.put(COL2,studentName);
        return this.getWritableDatabase().insert(STUDENTS_TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
    }

    public long insertTeacher(long teacherToBeMatched, String teacherName) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL1,teacherToBeMatched);
        cv.put(COL2,teacherName);
        return this.getWritableDatabase().insert(TEACHERS_TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getInfo() {
        //String query = "SELECT * FROM students Inner Join teachers ON student.matchingfield = teachers.matchingfield" ;
        //Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return this.getWritableDatabase().query(
                STUDENTS_TABLE_NAME + " INNER JOIN " + TEACHERS_TABLE_NAME +
                        " ON " + STUDENTS_TABLE_NAME + "." + COL1 + " = " +
                        TEACHERS_TABLE_NAME + "." + COL1,
                null,null,null,null,null,null
        );
    }
}
```

An activity that uses the database, adding some teachers (2) and some students (3 to match the first teacher and 2 to match the 2nd teacher) and then extracts them via the query.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper mDB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        mDB.insertTeacher(1,"Mr Jones");
        mDB.insertTeacher(2,"Mrs Smith");

        mDB.insertStudent(1,"Tom Smith");
        mDB.insertStudent(1,"Glenda Burrows");
        mDB.insertStudent(1,"Gloria Jennings");
        mDB.insertStudent(2,"Fred Sharp");
        mDB.insertStudent(2,"Mary Collins");

        Cursor csr = mDB.getInfo();

        int row = 1;
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("Processing row ").append(row++);
            for (int i=0; i < csr.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                sb.append("\n\t").append(csr.getColumnName(i)).append(" = " ).append(csr.getString(i));
            }
            Log.d("CURSORINFO",sb.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Running the above results in :-

```
2019-12-11 02:14:15.169 D/CURSORINFO: Processing row 1
        matchingfield = 1
        field1 = Tom Smith
        field2 = null
        field3 = null
        field4 = null
        matchingfield = 1
        field1 = Mr Jones
        field2 = null
        field3 = null
        field4 = null
2019-12-11 02:14:15.169 D/CURSORINFO: Processing row 2
        matchingfield = 1
        field1 = Glenda Burrows
        field2 = null
        field3 = null
        field4 = null
        matchingfield = 1
        field1 = Mr Jones
        field2 = null
        field3 = null
        field4 = null
2019-12-11 02:14:15.169 D/CURSORINFO: Processing row 3
        matchingfield = 1
        field1 = Gloria Jennings
        field2 = null
        field3 = null
        field4 = null
        matchingfield = 1
        field1 = Mr Jones
        field2 = null
        field3 = null
        field4 = null
2019-12-11 02:14:15.170 D/CURSORINFO: Processing row 4
        matchingfield = 2
        field1 = Fred Sharp
        field2 = null
        field3 = null
        field4 = null
        matchingfield = 2
        field1 = Mrs Smith
        field2 = null
        field3 = null
        field4 = null
2019-12-11 02:14:15.170 D/CURSORINFO: Processing row 5
        matchingfield = 2
        field1 = Mary Collins
        field2 = null
        field3 = null
        field4 = null
        matchingfield = 2
        field1 = Mrs Smith
        field2 = null
        field3 = null
        field4 = null
```

## Multiple Database Example

The **SyncStudentsHelper** class

```
public class SyncStudentsHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "students";
    public static final String COL1 = "matchingfield";
    public static final String COL2 = "field1";
    public static final String COL3 = "field2";
    public static final String COL4 = "field3";
    public static final String COL5 = "field4";

    public SyncStudentsHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String create_students_table_sql =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME +
                        "(" +
                        COL1 + " INTEGER," +
                        COL2 + " TEXT," +
                        COL3 + " TEXT," +
                        COL4 + " TEXT," +
                        COL5 + " TEXT" +
                        ")"
                ;
        db.execSQL(create_students_table_sql);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public long insertStudent(long teacherToMatch, String studentName) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL1,teacherToMatch);
        cv.put(COL2,studentName);
        return this.getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
    }
}
```

The **SyncTeachersHelper** class :-

```
public class SyncTeachersHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "teachers";
    public static final String COL1 = "matchingfield";
    public static final String COL2 = "field1";
    public static final String COL3 = "field2";
    public static final String COL4 = "field3";
    public static final String COL5 = "field4";

    public SyncTeachersHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String create_teachers_table_sql =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME +
                        "(" +
                        COL1 + " INTEGER," +
                        COL2 + " TEXT," +
                        COL3 + " TEXT," +
                        COL4 + " TEXT," +
                        COL5 + " TEXT" +
                        ")"
                ;
        db.execSQL(create_teachers_table_sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public long insertTeacher(long teacherToBeMatched, String teacherName) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL1,teacherToBeMatched);
        cv.put(COL2,teacherName);
        return this.getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
    }
}
```

The Activity code (for both Single and Multiple) :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper mDB;
    SyncTeachersHelper mTDB;
    SyncStudentsHelper mSDB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        mDB.insertTeacher(1,"Mr Jones");
        mDB.insertTeacher(2,"Mrs Smith");

        mDB.insertStudent(1,"Tom Smith");
        mDB.insertStudent(1,"Glenda Burrows");
        mDB.insertStudent(1,"Gloria Jennings");
        mDB.insertStudent(2,"Fred Sharp");
        mDB.insertStudent(2,"Mary Collins");

        Cursor csr = mDB.getInfo();

        int row = 1;
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("Processing row ").append(row++);
            for (int i=0; i < csr.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                sb.append("\n\t").append(csr.getColumnName(i)).append(" = " ).append(csr.getString(i));
            }
            Log.d("CURSORINFO",sb.toString());
        }

        Log.d("STAGE2","Now using dual databases");
        // USING Seperate Databases
        mTDB = new SyncTeachersHelper(this);
        mTDB.insertTeacher(1,"Mr Jones");
        mTDB.insertTeacher(2,"Mrs Smith");
        mTDB.close();

        mSDB = new SyncStudentsHelper(this);
        mSDB.insertStudent(1,"Tom Smith");
        mSDB.insertStudent(1,"Glenda Burrows");
        mSDB.insertStudent(1,"Gloria Jennings");
        mSDB.insertStudent(2,"Fred Sharp");
        mSDB.insertStudent(2,"Mary Collins");

        SQLiteDatabase studentsdb = mSDB.getWritableDatabase();
        String  attached = "attached_teacher";
        studentsdb.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '" + this.getDatabasePath(SyncTeachersHelper.TABLE_NAME) +"' AS " + attached);

        String fromclause = SyncStudentsHelper.TABLE_NAME + " INNER JOIN " + attached + "." + SyncTeachersHelper.TABLE_NAME +
                " ON " + SyncStudentsHelper.TABLE_NAME + "." + SyncStudentsHelper.COL1 + " = " +
                SyncTeachersHelper.TABLE_NAME + "." + SyncTeachersHelper.COL1;
        Log.d("STAGE2"," From clause for query is \n\t" + fromclause);
        csr = studentsdb.query(
        SyncStudentsHelper.TABLE_NAME + " INNER JOIN " + attached + "." + SyncTeachersHelper.TABLE_NAME +
                " ON " + SyncStudentsHelper.TABLE_NAME + "." + SyncStudentsHelper.COL1 + " = " +
                SyncTeachersHelper.TABLE_NAME + "." + SyncTeachersHelper.COL1,
                null,null,null,null,null,null
        );

        row = 1;
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("Processing row ").append(row++);
            for (int i=0; i < csr.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                sb.append("\n\t").append(csr.getColumnName(i)).append(" = " ).append(csr.getString(i));
            }
            Log.d("CURSORINFO",sb.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the FROM clause for the query (which includes the JOIN) is :-

```
students INNER JOIN attached_teacher.teachers ON students.matchingfield = teachers.matchingfield
```

The result (for STAGE2) being :-

```
2019-12-11 02:43:59.699 D/STAGE2: Now using dual databases
2019-12-11 02:43:59.773 D/STAGE2:  From clause for query is 
        students INNER JOIN attached_teacher.teachers ON students.matchingfield = teachers.matchingfield
2019-12-11 02:43:59.774 D/CURSORINFO: Processing row 1
        matchingfield = 1
        field1 = Tom Smith
        field2 = null
        field3 = null
        field4 = null
        matchingfield = 1
        field1 = Mr Jones
        field2 = null
        field3 = null
        field4 = null
2019-12-11 02:43:59.774 D/CURSORINFO: Processing row 2
        matchingfield = 1
        field1 = Glenda Burrows
        field2 = null
        field3 = null
        field4 = null
        matchingfield = 1
        field1 = Mr Jones
        field2 = null
        field3 = null
        field4 = null
2019-12-11 02:43:59.774 D/CURSORINFO: Processing row 3
        matchingfield = 1
        field1 = Gloria Jennings
        field2 = null
        field3 = null
        field4 = null
        matchingfield = 1
        field1 = Mr Jones
        field2 = null
        field3 = null
        field4 = null
2019-12-11 02:43:59.775 D/CURSORINFO: Processing row 4
        matchingfield = 2
        field1 = Fred Sharp
        field2 = null
        field3 = null
        field4 = null
        matchingfield = 2
        field1 = Mrs Smith
        field2 = null
        field3 = null
        field4 = null
2019-12-11 02:43:59.775 D/CURSORINFO: Processing row 5
        matchingfield = 2
        field1 = Mary Collins
        field2 = null
        field3 = null
        field4 = null
        matchingfield = 2
        field1 = Mrs Smith
        field2 = null
        field3 = null
        field4 = null
```

Comment: Hi MikeT. I have following line "        db.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE teacherhelper.teachers as teacherdb");
" but I get error "no such column: teacherhelper.teachers  (code 1): "

Comment: @JamesHickling In the query you have `teachersdatabase.teachers.matchingfield` as the table has been defined via JOIN the column you should only use `teachers.matchingfield`. Hence why I output the FROM clause as `students INNER JOIN attached_teacher.teachers ON students.matchingfield = teachers.matchingfield`.

Comment: I did exactly what you told me above, still, get the error no such column: teachers

Comment: In your example you have the following,    `studentsdb.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '" + this.getDatabasePath(SyncTeachersHelper.TABLE_NAME) +"' AS " + attached);` -, 'how is `this.getDatabasePath `defined

Comment: @JamesHickling **this** equates to the **Context** and `getDatabasePath(databse_name)` is a method of Context that gets the path where, by default, the database will be saved. i.e. a reason why a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper requires the Context is to get the default location (`data/data/the_package/databases/the_database_name`) (it gets the package from the Context). So it is basically saying get the **connection** to the database as per the name. Ooops didn't notice that you have the table name not the path coded in the ATTACH statement.

Comment: Because I have 2 Helper classes, for students and teachers and I don't have database names (only have a table name defined on both files), how I would define the path in my `attach` statement

Comment: @JamesHickling You do have database names (2 of them), it is just that they are the same as the table names. So you use the table name (aka the database name) for the parameter passed to `getDatabasePath` of the database to be attached. The Multi Database Example replicates the scenario you have and only differs in that the class for the Teachers was made up as the code was not in the question .

Comment: Thank you @MikeT. I have commented out the SQL query and only have the following line ` ` `db.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE  SyncTeachersHelper.teahers AS teachersdatabase");`, I still get the error `E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: SyncTeachersHelper.teacher`

Comment: @JamesHickling I believe that I have fully explained why "ATTACH DATABASE SyncTeachersHelper.teahers AS teachersdatabase" will not work. SyncTeachersHelper.teahers is not the **path**  to the database file as is needed to connect the database to be attached. The **path**, is easily obtained via the Context's `getDatabasePath` method. As is shown in the answer. I'd suggest that attaching a database is beyond you current skill level and that you should look to using a single database with multiple tables as per the initial answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply apply SQL command to SQLite:

```
ATTACH DATABASE path_file_name AS my_database_name;
```

then later apply your SQL command

```
select * from mytable
    left join my_database_name.my_other_table
    on field_name = database_name.my_other_table.myfield_name
```

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html